# LEFT JOIN with more fields in the right table

Tags: mysql

I have a problem!
My shops table contains 4 rows, each containing a shop name, ID and other data relevant to that shop.

I also have a "bind" table where I select which product categories should be visible in which shops. Naturally the bind table will contain more rows... I would like to select all the shops from the shops table, and join only the rows in the right table, the bind table, if the shop ID is the same.

```
SELECT * , b.categoryId as bindCategory
FROM shops

LEFT JOIN bind_shop_category AS b
ON shops.shopId = b.shopId
```

If I do it like that, I get all the binds, with their corresponding shop data, not just the shops and their corresponding bind data. :P

This is very confusing, and I'm not sure I formulated the question 100%.

Uhm... expected data:

```
  shopId          shopName         bind.categoryId
    1               shop1
    2               shop2            category1
    3               shop3            category1
    4               shop4
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
SELECT S.* , B.categoryId as bindCategory
FROM shops S
   LEFT JOIN bind_shop_category B
       ON B.shopId = S.shopId
```

Comment: Would the b and B references above conflict or are they not case sensitive?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm.  Possibly you mean:

```
SELECT shops.*, b.categoryId as bindCategory
FROM shops
LEFT JOIN bind_shop_category AS b
ON shops.shopId = b.shopId
```

(or, the way I'd write it:)

```
SELECT shops.*, b.categoryId as bindCategory
FROM shops
LEFT JOIN bind_shop_category AS b
USING (shopId)
```

Answer (score 0):

After the post was updated.  You want the following.

```
SELECT s.ShopId, s.ShopName , b.categoryId as bindCategory
FROM shops
    LEFT OUTER JOIN bind_shop_category AS b
         ON (shops.shopId = b.shopId)
ORDER BY s.ShopId
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to simply list all the categories for each shop in a single row, you can use GROUP_CONCAT

```
SELECT s.shopId, s.shopName, GROUP_CONCAT(b.categoryId)
FROM shops s
LEFT JOIN bind_shop_category AS b ON (s.shopId = b.shopId)
GROUP BY s.shopId
```

Output will be something like this...

```
1               shop1            NULL
2               shop2            category1,category2
3               shop3            category1
```

Change the LEFT JOIN to an INNER JOIN to only show shops with at least one category.